# While loops that generate random numbers

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python and I am trying to figure out how to write a program that will generate and display random numbers between 1 and 23 until the sum of the numbers generated is greater than 200 or two 7s are generated all in one piece of code. So far I have made the below; I am stuck on how to add the two 7s to my statement.

```
from random import randrange
sum = 0
while sum < 200 or sum ==7:
    randnum = randrange(1, 24)
    sum = sum + randnum
    print("Random number = ", randnum, " Sum = ", sum)
```

Comment: Do you want to stop when _any_ two sevens are generated, or when _two sevens in a row_ are generated?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Look at the logic in your while statement. You have to keep track of how many times a "7" is generated. Also, your sum must be GREATER than 200.

Comment: @Jesuisme She wants to keep generating new numbers if the sum is less than 200, so I believe that portion of her logic is correct.

Comment: @JohnGordon One of the stopping conditions is sum > 200. As currently written, the logic fails if sum == 200.

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable to remember the previous random number.

```
from random import randrange
sum = 0
randnum = 0
prevnum = 0
while sum < 200 and not (randnum == 7 and prevnum == 7):
    randnum = randrange(1, 24)
    sum = sum + randnum
    print("Random number = ", randnum, " Sum = ", sum)
    prevnum = randnum
```